# Swift URL appendPathComponent replaces ? with %3F

Tags: swift

I have a router which contains the lines

```
var url = URL(string: MyRouter.baseURLString)!

url.appendPathComponent(relativePath)
```

This replaces "?" with "%3F" which is rejected by the API server. How can I fix this? It's wrong to encode that character.

Comment: It's wrong to include "?" into the path components. It is used as a separator between path and query, so it NEEDS to be percent-encoded if you really want it in the path. If you want to create a URL with query, like `https://example.com?name=value`, you may try to use `URLComponents` or just use string concatenation.

Comment: I changed it to use string concatenation. The relative path was in the form /search?since=1

Comment: Have you successfully made it? If you find some difficulty still now, please edit your question and add some details about it.

Comment: you need to create string of your url and set URLEncoding like
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51894621/3110023

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because the `?` isn't part of a path. It's a separator to signal the beginning of the query string. You can read about the different components of a URL in [this article](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGMCP_5.1.0/com.ibm.cics.ts.internet.doc/topics/dfhtl_uricomp.html). Each component has its set of valid characters, anything not in that set needs to be percent-escaped. The best option is to use `URLComponents` which handles the escaping automatically for you:

```
var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: MyRouter.baseURLString)!
urlComponents.queryItems = [
    URLQueryItem(name: "username", value: "jsmith"),
    URLQueryItem(name: "password", value: "password")
]

let url = urlComponents.url!
```